# Backup Esxi virtual machines to external USB hard drive; no vCenter, no other servers. Is this sane?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but there seems to be a number of options floating around. I'm running an Esxi server (v6.0) with about 4.5Tb of storage that I'd like to back up. I've a 6Tb USB drive with USB3. We're just running the free version so that might rule out some tools.

I can't mount the drive directly to the VM as this only supports Fat16, so 2Tb drives. I don't want to mount it on a linux server as Esx controllers limit me to USB2.

I've successfully passed the drive and controller through to a windows client. I can rsync the files from the hypervisor through the windows store to the drive. Hopefully rsync will make restarting a bit easier, should there be a fail.

I understand I can't back up the VM I'm working from.

I really can't see a better way of doing this, is this about the best way? There's about fifteen VM's on here.

Will restoration be a matter of copying the files back to an Esxi (v6 or higher) server and adding to the inventory?

Comment: ESXi doesn't have rsync, what and how exactly are you backing up?

Comment: Oh, probably just a standard copy then. I'm going to try and backup everything all the datastores, except the VM I'm using.

Comment: If the VMs aren't suspended or powered off during the backup, you'll likely just have 4.5Tb worth of garbage.

Comment: Hence the "I understand I can't back up the VM I'm working from" comment.

Answer (score 0):

William Lam has a shell script to back up running VMs.

https://github.com/lamw/ghettoVCB

Documentation is here:

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VI-VMware-ESX-3-5-Documents/ghettoVCB-sh-Free-alternative-for-backing-up-VM-s-for-ESX-i-3-5/ta-p/2773570

Change the VM_BACKUP_VOLUME value to the location of the USB.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good option to backup just VMs files. Why not implement a backup solution like Veeam? You can use your USB as a repository.
Veeam free license is the best option to your problem, and you get more tools to recover VMs and files.
Give it a try, just need a Windows Server 2012 R2 or later.

Comment: Veeam does not work with the free License of ESXi.